# Increasing number by scrolling in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

Is there a package in GitHub's Atom code editor to increase number values (numbers, px, em, %, etc.) by scrolling over them? I thought this could be really handy, but couldn't find one that does that.

If there is not, maybe somebody with the proper knowledge could make such package? For example, you could increase value by hovering the mouse over the value, holding `ctrl + alt` and scrolling up, but decrase it by scrolling down.

Comment: I've not seen anything, I'll add it to my list of things to do.